# Error calling wcf service by ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, wcf

iwent to run this simple wcf method using ajax in html page as test but it doesn't run at all and idont know whats the problem

![error message][1]

IcustomerService page

> [OperationContract]
>           [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
>            string GetTEST();

service.svc page

> ```
> [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
>     public class Service1 : IcustomerService
>     {
>
>         public string GetTEST()
>         {
>             return "OKKKKKKKK";
>         }
> ```

here is my html page

> ```html
> > 
> >      <title></title>
> >         <script type="text/javascript"></script>
> >         <script type="text/javascript"src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
> >          <script  type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.intellisense.js"></script>
> >         <script  type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
> >        <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
> >           <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>
> > 
> > 
> >         <script type="text/javascript">
> >             var url = 'http://localhost:43315/Service1.svc/'
> > 
> >             function GetProducts() {
> > 
> >                 var response;
> > 
> >                 $.ajax({
> >                     async: true,
> >                     type: 'post',
> >                     url: url + 'GetTEST',
> >                     contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
> >                     dataType: 'json',
> >                     success: function () {
> >                         alert("yahooooooooo");
> >                     },
> > 
> >                     error: function (e) {
> >                         alert("Error  : " + e.statusText);
> >                     }
> >                 });
> >             }
> > 
> >
> ```

here is web.config page

> ```
>  <system.serviceModel>
> <behaviors>
>   <serviceBehaviors>
>     <behavior name="Service1Behavior">
>
>       <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
>
>       <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
>     </behavior>
>   </serviceBehaviors>
>   <endpointBehaviors>
>     <behavior name="WebBehavior">
>       <enableWebScript/>
>     </behavior>
>   </endpointBehaviors>
> </behaviors>
> <services>
>   <service behaviorConfiguration="Service1Behavior"
>             name="WcfService1.Service1">
>     <endpoint address=""
>           binding="basicHttpBinding"
>           contract="WcfService1.IService1" />
>     <endpoint address="Web"
>               binding="webHttpBinding"
>               contract="WcfService1.IService1"
>               behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" />
>   </service>
> </services>
> <protocolMapping>
>     <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
> </protocolMapping>    
> <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />   </system.serviceModel>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Is URL correct? I think port might have changed. Host service in IIS then try.

Comment: when i run To test Service1.svc   its give this ithink this main its already hosted "this service, you will need to create a client and use it to call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the command line with the following syntax:

svcutil.exe http://localhost:13243/Service1.svc?wsdl

You can also access the service description as a single file:

http://localhost:13243/Service1.svc?singleWsdl"

Comment: Ok. But is the service running when you are testing? Have you tested your service using WCFTestclient? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364(v=vs.110).aspx. Also Jquery variable url and your local variable seems to be same. Can you please rename your local variable and try?